# Electrocaloric effect in triboelectrically charged particles under external electric field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electrostatics, temperature

My understanding: electrocaloric effect relies on polarized molecules lining up to an external electric field, which lowers the local entropy and thus heat is given off to the surroundings. When the field is removed, the molecular dipoles again arrange randomly, which increases the local entropy, thus heat is taken in from the surroundings.

I ask about a macro level system. Here I have micron sized particles, each particle made of two hemispheres using different materials from the triboelectric series.

[image]

These serve as my "molecules". Upon initial shaking, the surfaces rub and so each particle has a dipole.

Before shaking:
[image]

After shaking:
[image]

Now I turn on an electric field and vibrate the container a little so the particles loosen and align themselves to the field. This vibrating is kind of like of how they used to hammer the living hell out of heated iron in a strong magnetic field, so the magnetic domains align as the object solidified.

[image]

Now I can't think of any reason why this won't display the electrocaloric effect. And since here we don't rely on the molecule shapes, crystallization, polarization and the intermolecular forces that prevent the dipoles from completely aligning themselves, I think this could display interesting levels of cooling and heating.

Of course, I'm a nobody, so to you experts I hand over my question.

Will this work, and if yes, can we quantify the effect using any equations?